# Watch Face is not syncing to wearable

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing a watch face. The project consists of watch face and handheld app to report the mobile battery. There is no actual companion app - the app is even hidden from the drawer.
I'm encountering the issue that when I install the app on the phone the face is not syncing on the watch.
I'm compliant with almost everything I've found on the internet:

1. The apk is generated by Android Studio - release version, signed, the wear app is in the res/raw folder.
2. Permissions are the same for mobile and wear app.
3. The dependencies are set correctly.
4. APK is installed via ADB, Watch app are force synced ...

It is worth mentioning that the mobile app does not have an activity or something. So there is no way to manually start it.

Is there anything I'm missing. From my perspective there is not reason not to work ...

**Mobile Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="name.name" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >-->

        <service android:name="name.name.BatteryListener"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
            android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Mobile Gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2"
    compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'

}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
        'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
        'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
        'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "name.name"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }
```

**Wear Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="qualiss.qualissfacewatch" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <service
            android:name="name.name.MyWatchFace"
            android:label="Name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
                android:resource="@drawable/preview_square"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
                android:resource="@drawable/preview_circle" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.companionConfigurationAction"
                android:value="com.example.android.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_ANALOG" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>

        <service android:name="name.name.BatteryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Wear Gradle**:

```
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



dependencies {


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
        'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
        'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
        'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21

    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "name.name"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }
}
}
```

Both Gradle files were closely matched to Android Watch Face sample ... I was just desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed those 2 from **Wear** manifest:

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
```

To me it seems like the correct procedure for permissions should not be to have the same in mobile and wear manifest, but to inherit the wear permissions in mobile and not (also) vice versa.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. All the permissions from the wearable manifest need to be included in the mobile manifest (so the system knows what permissions are required when installing the app) but _not_ vice versa. Those permissions you removed are likely to be permissions that are not recognised or supported on Android Wear.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have identical set of permissions in phone and watch manifest files. It was reason for me in same situation.

Comment: As mentioned in the first post - yes, I do have the same set of permissions.

Comment: Check if you have your package on Watch `adb shell pm list packages`. If you have it then the error is in watchface description in manifest.

Comment: No, there is not package on the Watch. It looks like it is not installed/pushed at all. And I cannot figure it why ... I've even compared my app with the android watch face sample by Google and it all seems to be correct ...

Comment: Manual packaging is also not working ... updated first post with code.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your Wear manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.companionConfigurationAction"
            android:value="com.example.android.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_ANALOG" />
```

This looks like it is left over from the example code and is likely pointing to an Activity which does not exist in your mobile app. This could very likely cause a problem with deploying the watch face.

Try removing it and see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not ... the issue persist. The app is not synced automatically and it is not synced when I force-sync. Is there a way to check logcat without root?

Answer (score 0):

In your mobile gradle... you need to include this...

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(':Wearable')
```